# DataGridView filled with IList is not showing

Tags: c#, datagridview

i'm trying to display an Ilist< T > in a datagridview, 
but even tought my Ilist is not empty, the datagridview is not showing.

Here is my code :

```
public partial class display_old_request : UserControl
{
    public display_old_request(request request)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillData(request);
        this.Show();
    }

    void fillData(request request)
    {
        IList<request> old_request_to_display = request.Get_old_request_information();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = old_request_to_display;


    }
}
```

*request* is an object link to a product which contains severals attributes : name of a product requested, quantity requested for this product..

Get_old_request_information() is a method which return an Ilist  of past requests on a particular product.

I tried several things to get it run : Datagridview1.refresh() /or to use a bindinglist but nothing seems to work

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: try to add line dataGridView1.Bind();

Comment: @KreminT is that a webforms thing? I think OP is using Win Forms.

Comment: Hi, Correct i' using win Forms so dataGridView1.Bind(); is not available

Thanks for your help